# Set webpack output path

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

I have recently upgraded webpack 1 to 2, previously we could have given relative `output.path` but now the absolute path is necessary. My all bundle file goes to `/static/v4/angular/dist/` so in Webpack 1 I had given this like `output.path: '../static/v4/angular/dist'`. Now how can I modify this so that it works same as previously? Here is my directory structure:

```
myapp
  |
  angular
     |
     config
  |
  static
    |
    v4/angular/ // Here I want my files to go
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is convert it to an absolute path. You can use [`path.resolve`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths) for this.

```
path.resolve(__dirname, '../static/v4/angular/dist')
```

[`__dirname`](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_dirname) is the directory of the currently executed file (your webpack config) and then you add the relative path from there. And `path.resolve` will give you the absolute path of combining them.